# response_type and grant_type in OAuth2.0/OIDC specifications

Tags: openid, identity, openid-connect

I am currently working on the specification "CIBA" of openID. This specification says it is mandatory to have a new grant_type **urn:openid:params:grant-type:ciba**. So I am writing a new grant_type [handlers & validators for them]. But is it essential to write new response_type? 
Can't we use `response_type=code` in authorization request and then use `grant_type=urn:openid:params:grant-type:ciba` in token request to get Access & ID Token from IdP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the CIBA flows are started by sending a request to a backchannel authentication endpoint, not to an authorization endpoint.

The backchannel authentication endpoint is a new endpoint defined in the CIBA specification. The endpoint does not recognize the `response_type` parameter, so you don't have to care about values for the parameter. Note that CIBA flows don't use the authorization endpoint.

See [“CIBA”, a new authentication/authorization technology in 2019, explained by an implementer](https://medium.com/@darutk/ciba-a-new-authentication-authorization-technology-in-2019-explained-by-an-implementer-d1e0ac1311b4) for details.

Comment: Thank you Takahiko Kawasaki !